# Get java.util.Calendar from days since epoch

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a variable containing the days since the [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of `1970-01-01` for a certain date.

Does someone know the way to convert this variable to a `java.util.Calendar`?

Comment: *which* epoch? [J2000.0 or something else?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(new Date(0));

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1000);

System.err.println(c.getTime());
```

---

A note regarding time zones:

A new `GregorianCalendar` instance is created using the default time zone of the system the program is running on. Since Epoch is relative to UTC (GMT in Java) any time zone different from UTC must be handled with care. The following program illustrates the problem:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1"));

Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTimeInMillis(0);

System.err.println(c.getTime());
System.err.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
System.err.println(c.getTime());
System.err.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
```

This prints

```
Wed Dec 31 23:00:00 GMT-01:00 1969
365
Thu Jan 01 23:00:00 GMT-01:00 1970
1
```

This demonstrates that it is not enough to use e.g. `c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)`. In this case one must always take into account what time of day it is. This can be avoided by using GMT explicitly when creating the `GregorianCalendar`: `new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))`. If the calendar is created such, the output is:

```
Wed Dec 31 23:00:00 GMT-01:00 1969
1
Thu Jan 01 23:00:00 GMT-01:00 1970
2
```

Now the calendar returns useful values. The reason why the `Date` returned by `c.getTime()` is still "off" is that the `toString()` method uses the default `TimeZone` to build the string. At the top we set this to GMT-1 so everything is normal.

Comment: Together with all the other answers until now, this will give an incorrect date for time zones before (west of) UTC, unless you consider the time zone (add one day) when evaluating the result.

Comment: @jarnbjo: I can't confirm that in tests. Could you provide a small example?

Comment: Add "TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1"));" before your code and add one day instead of 1000 (to make the problem obvious). The  output will be January 1st, 1970, although January 2nd is expected.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Why wouldn't it be expected? The output of the `Date` is `Thu Jan 01 23:00:00 GMT-01:00 1970`. This is exactly the same moment in time just in another TZ. Unix time is always relative to UTC (with all the caveats mentioned in the relevant Wikipedia article).

Comment: I must admit that the question is slightly ambiguous, but I find it hard to accept that one day after January 1st, 1970 should be January 1st, 1970.

Comment: @jarnbjo: If you describe Epoch in GMT-1 it is `Wed Dec 31 23:00:00 GMT-01:00 1969`, _not_ Jan 1st, 1970.

Comment: @musiKk: MrThys writes about "the epoch" in a context of dates and even answers that he means January 1st, 1970. Even if he's not 100% clear on this, I doubt that he is asking for anything else but finding the date "N days after January 1st, 1970". Sorry, but your initial answer simply did not answer that question.

Comment: @jarnbjo: How about my updated version then? :) (I still disagree but more clarity is never wrong.)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes in Java 8 and later. In one line:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(1000);
```

Calling [`ofEpochDay(long epochDay)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofEpochDay-long-) obtains an instance of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) from the epoch day count.

Comment: FYI: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Further adapted for Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Comment: Do you know why this much complex logic is written for epochDay  in the API. Seems pretty confusing

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: If you look up into the method api  it's kinda huge logic written.

Comment: Much of [that source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/LocalDate.java#LocalDate.toEpochDay%28%29) is for handling [leap year](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).

Answer (score 3):

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, daysSinceEpoch);
```